# animating a circle to grow

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

i am animating an UIImageView with an image of a circle that grows and fades which repeats:

```
-(void)animateOuterCircle
{
    NSLog(@"animating circles");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 
                          delay:.5
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^{
                         self.outerCircle.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.25, .25);
                     }
                     completion:nil];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 
                          delay:.5
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^{    
                         self.outerCircle.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
                         self.outerCircle.alpha = 0;
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.outerCircle];
}
```

i call this method in viewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{        
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(animateOuterCircle) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    //other code
}
```

It will animate fine when i load mainView. the issue is i load view2 and dismiss view2, when i come back to mainView, it is not animating anymore.

any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT: the methods are being called:

```
2012-03-15 14:11:13.946[1529:17903] view2 canceled  //dismissing view2
2012-03-15 14:11:13.947[1529:17903] mapView viewWillAppear fired
2012-03-15 14:11:13.948[1529:17903] mapView viewWillAppear end
2012-03-15 14:11:14.352[1529:17903] mapView viewDidAppear fired
2012-03-15 14:11:14.353[1529:17903] animating circles
2012-03-15 14:11:14.354[1529:17903] mapView viewDidAppear end
```

EDIT 2:

```
-(IBAction) fourthBtn:(id)sender
{
    view2 *view2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2"];
    [self presentModalViewController:view2 animated:YES];    
}
```

dismissing view 2:

```
-(IBAction) cancel:(id) sender
{    
    NSLog(@"heir canceled");

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

also, i don't stop the animation myself at any point in my code.

Comment: Perhaps `viewDidAppear` isn't getting called? Show the view switching code.

Comment: Is viewDidAppear even getting called? Are you stopping the animation when you load view2 yourself?

Comment: viewDidAppear does get called and animateOuterCircle does get called.

Comment: Have you checked using the debugger if your reference to the layer is still valid the second time (when the animation is not occurring)? Nothing happens when you send messages to `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i re-did some code;

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.outerCircle removeFromSuperview];
    [self.innerCircle removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.innerCircle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"inner-circle.png"]];
    self.innerCircle.frame = CGRectMake(self.innerCircle.frame.origin.x, self.innerCircle.frame.origin.y, 30, 30);

    self.outerCircle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"outer-circle.png"]];
    self.outerCircle.frame = CGRectMake(self.outerCircle.frame.origin.x, self.outerCircle.frame.origin.y, 40, 40);

    [self.view insertSubview:self.innerCircle belowSubview:HUD];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.outerCircle belowSubview:HUD];

//other code
}
```

with these changes, it behaves as i want it too.

i think it had something to do with trying to animate the outerCircle a second time (it was already animating from first viewDidAppear, and when viewDidAppear was called a second time, it re-animated an already animating image and just borked it completely).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that viewDidAppear is not being called, because from the perspective of that view, it never disappears.

Depending on how you are creating and displaying the view2, would this work within view2 when you close it?

```
[parentViewController viewDidAppear:YES];
```

Comment: viewDidAppear is being called and my animate method is being called; its just not doing the animation.

Comment: Can you show us how you are presenting then dismissing view2?

Comment: Out of curiosity - try changing the color of the outerCircle just to see if it is still referenced. If not then maybe it's not being retained/referenced properly. How are you creating outer circle?